# How to find page width in Opera 12 (for Desktop Windows)?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, opera, browser-detection, document-body

I want to access full page width & height in Opera. Note I am not asking about Viewport's height or width, I want page's/document's width & height. I am using Opera 12.12

I have tried the following:

1. document.body.scrollWidth/Height
2. document.body.offsetWidth/Height
3. window.innerWidth/Height
4. document.body.clientWidth/Height

And all of them gives viewport's width/height.

Please use the following link:
http://jsfiddle.net/RQhYR/

Or use the following HTML Page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<body>
    <div style="width:2000px;height:2000px;background-color: blue;"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(window.outerWidth + "," + window.outerHeight);
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You have _tried_... and what did they return?

Comment: "And all of them gives viewport's width/height."

Comment: @tanmaykhandelwal: Why not? They could be the same. Please make a demo where they shouldn't be the viewport dimensions but are.

Comment: Make a simple HTML page and open it in Opera:
//Page starts here
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<div style="width:2000px;height:2000px;background-color: blue;"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(window.outerWidth + "," + window.outerHeight);
</script>
</html>
//Page ends here

Here the viewport size will be around the resolution of your screen, but the page size will be 2000px x 2000px (dimensions of the div).
In this case the alert is showing viewport's size in Opera, but not the page's size.

Comment: Please use the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/RQhYR/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting the correct values from `body.offsetWidth/Height`, `body.scrollWidth/Height` and `body.clientWidth/Height` (using the same build as you). Only [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.innerWidth)/[`Height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.innerHeight) is *supposed* to return browser window viewport.

Maybe you've got some odd CSS that sets the dimensions of the body to the viewport and puts the scrollbar on an element somewhere inside. In your case, I'm getting the expected values of 2000 x 2000 px from the `scrollWidth/Height` of the `<html>`, see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RQhYR/1/).

Comment: @Bergi...After seeing the demo, document.body.scrollWidth doesn't work but document.documentElement.scrollWidth works. It gives page's size in all browsers except the IE Quirks Mode. Thanks Bergi!

Answer (score 0):

Try these on for size:

```
window.outerHeight;
window.outerWidth;
```

Comment: Same, viewport's width/height

Comment: @tanmaykhandelwal no it is not.

Comment: I am using Opera 12.12 for Windows Desktop and it is giving me viewport's dimensions. Info:
About Opera
Version information
Version: 12.12 
Build: 1707 
Platform: Win32 
System: Windows 7

Comment: @Neal: Yes, it is not the viewport. But it's [the dimensions of the browser window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.outerWidth), which the OP certainly does not want!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) I got the answer of my question. I have been doing some investigation about Page & Viewport sizes in different browsers and this is what I have found: [Google Doc Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsiIb2IL4qASdDczbW56a1d6NFpPTTNXX1pjOHJpZFE)