# CSS - Span divs the entire height of the page

Tags: html, css

I have coded my divs so that they (almost) appear perfectly. The correct divs are above/below each other and it spans the entire width of the page. What I am finding is that it is not spanning the entire height of the page. Any advise would be greatly appreciated! Also, I have a horizontal scroll bar that I would love to go away. :)

**CSS:**

```
body {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 11px;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro", Arial, Helvetica, Arial, 'DejaVu Sans', 'Liberation Sans', Freesans, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

.container_16 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 960px;
  margin-top:0px;
  padding-top:0px;
      min-height:800px; 
    background-image:url(../images/Content_bkg.gif);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(0,0,0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(0,0,0);
}
.container_24 {
    background-image: url(../images/headerFooter_bkg.gif);
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(71, 89, 32);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(0,0,0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(0,0,0);
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
       <div class="container_24">
            <div class="grid_16">
                <input type="text" value="Username" /><input type="text" value="Password" /><input type="button" value="Submit" /><span class="mainLink">Register</span>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="container_16">
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Body" runat="server">

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </form>
       </div>
       <div class="container_24"></div>

</body>
```

UPDATE:
This is what my code looks like with the wrapper concept provided below.

```
.wrapper{
    height:100%;
}

.container_16 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 960px;
  margin-top:0px;
  padding-top:0px;
    background-image:url(../images/Content_bkg.gif);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(0,0,0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(0,0,0);
}
.container_24 {
    background-image: url(../images/headerFooter_bkg.gif);
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(71, 89, 32);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(0,0,0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(0,0,0);
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="container_24">
            <div class="grid_16">
                <input type="text" value="Username" /><input type="text" value="Password" /><input type="button" value="Submit" /><span class="mainLink">Register</span>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="container_16">
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Body" runat="server">

                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </form>
       </div>
       <div class="container_24"></div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: First hint for CSS: don't mix and match inline and external CSS.  It is a pain to debug and makes for messy code.  You have a CSS definition for `container_16`, but you also have an inline style on that div.

Comment: Thanks - I forgot I even put that there. :) I've removed it and am updating my code above.

Answer (score 3):

you have explicitly given `height` to each container, the only way to have (visually) full height would be to enclose everything in a wrapper that has `height: 100%` or similar

**Edit:** clarification example :

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
     <!--Your stuff here-->
  </div>
</body>
```

in the above example, the wrapper gets 100% height, not the contents.

Comment: If I change the code to reflect a height of 100% in body and in container 16 then container 16 just disappears from view completely.

Comment: I had tried that earlier - it also does not fix it. (Same result as I outlined above). To clarify - Wrapper has height:100% and container 16 has a min-height of 100%

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use javascript to get the height of the page. Then do some math per container to get the correct ratio of container to height to fill the page.

Comment: Javascript is not needed in this instance.  I would consider this an inefficient recommendation.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding the question then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to exactly determine the height & width of the page. I have asked a similar question sometime before. Have a look: [How to find page width in Opera 12 (for Desktop Windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953913/how-to-find-page-width-in-opera-12-for-desktop-windows/13960641#13960641)

I did RnD on the same and came up with the [results](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsiIb2IL4qASdDczbW56a1d6NFpPTTNXX1pjOHJpZFE)